# How can I transfer a model to a Razor Component in Blazor server-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am using Blazor server-side to make a chat room.

For the style of receiving the message and sending the message is different, I made  a model named `MsgModel`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorApp1
{
    public class MsgModel: ComponentBase
    {
        public string MsgText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The razor components `ReceiveMsg.razor` and the `SendMsg.razor` are base on this model.

```
@inherits MsgModel
<h3>ReceiveMsg</h3>@MsgText
```

```
 @inherits MsgModel
 <h3>SendMsg</h3>@MsgText
```

In the `index.razor`, I wanna input the message text and display it immediately.

```
@page "/"

@foreach (MsgModel _MsgModel in MsgList)
{
    if (_MsgModel.GetType() == typeof(ReceiveMsg))
    {
        <ReceiveMsg></ReceiveMsg>
    }
    else
    {
        <SendMsg></SendMsg>
    }
}
<div id="inputDiv">
    <EditForm Model="_InputMsgModel" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitText">
        <InputText @bind-Value="_InputMsgModel.MsgText" />
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code{
    protected MsgModel _InputMsgModel { get; set; } = new MsgModel();
    protected List<MsgModel> MsgList { get; set; } = new List<MsgModel>();
     protected void SubmitText()
    {
        SendMsg _SendMsg = new SendMsg();
        _SendMsg.MsgText = _InputMsgModel.MsgText;
        MsgList.Add(_SendMsg);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is: in the `for` block, I should transfer the `_MsgModel` to the component. Meanwhile, I don't know how to transfer it yet.

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a strange and stupid way to solve this.

I add these code into the `MsgModel`:

```
[Parameter]
        public MsgModel TransferModel
        {
            set
            {
                CopyAll(value, this);
            }
        }
        private void CopyAll<T>(T source, T target)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            foreach (var sourceProperty in type.GetProperties())
            {
                if (sourceProperty.Name != "TransferModel")
                {
                    var targetProperty = type.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
                    targetProperty.SetValue(target, sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null), null);
                }
            }
        }
```

And change the `for` block like this:

```
@foreach (Models.MsgModel _MsgModel in MsgList)
    {
        if (_MsgModel.GetType() == typeof(ReceiveMsg))
        {
            <ReceiveMsg ShowFullImage="@ShowFullImage" TransferModel="_MsgModel"></ReceiveMsg>
        }
        else
        {
            <SendMsg ShowFullImage="@ShowFullImage" TransferModel="_MsgModel"></SendMsg>
        }
    }
```

What a stupid way it is!